# PDO - Display Rows from Select statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been struggling for a while to get the following code to run, it isnt returning anything:

```
try {
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbDatabase", $dbUser, $dbPass);
  $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
  $STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT * FROM `component`');
  # setting the fetch mode
  $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  while($row = $STH->fetchAll()) {
    echo $row['cid'] . "\n";
    echo $row['cdesc'] . "\n";
    echo $row['cinfo'] . "\n";
  }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "I'm sorry. I'm afraid I can't do that.";
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated. Rgds, Stew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) method.
Also wrong usage of fetchAll.

See [Example #1 Fetch all remaining rows in a result set](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetchall-examples)

Another example with fetchMode:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT * FROM `component`');
$STH->execute();
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// since PDOStatement implements Traversable you can directly iterate
foreach ($STH as $row) {
    echo $row['cid'] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) returns all the rows, if you want to iterate over the results you can use [`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

```
while($row = $STH->fetch())
```

Or if you want to stick with `fetchAll()`:

```
$rows = $STH->fetchAll();
foreach($row in $rows){
  ...
}
```

As bitWorking pointed out you are also missing the call to `execute`:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT * FROM `component`');
$STH->execute();
# setting the fetch mode
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I don't mind which one I use, I cant get either to work though.

Comment: You missed the call to `execute`, and I did too, see @bitWorking answer.

Comment: Out of interest, which is better to use between 'fetch' and 'fetchALL'

Comment: To be honest I don't think there's such a big difference, the only difference is that it could be that you want to fetch some rows until you find one and then break out of the loop, then using `fetchAll` would be a waist but in the end the difference is minimal if you don't have a very large result set.